# C# access to TreeNode variable file.CreationTime outside treeView

Tags: c#, treeview

I need to access to file.CreationTime of selected node in treeView and display it in label outside treeView.
I added .Tag and now in works great when directory is selected, but when file is selected I'm getting that treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag is null and application crashes.

Does anyone have idea how to fix it?

```
private void ListDirectory(TreeView treeView, string path)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
        var rootDirectoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);

        treeView1.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(rootDirectoryInfo));

    }

private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
    {    
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name + " (" + DirectorySize(new DirectoryInfo(directoryInfo.FullName)) + " bytes)" + " (" + directoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos().Length + " files)");
        foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));

        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
            directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name + " (" + file.Length + " bytes)"+ file.CreationTime));

        directoryNode.Tag = directoryInfo;

        return directoryNode;
    }
    private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag!=null)

        { 
        var directoryInfo = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag as DirectoryInfo;
        var creationTime = directoryInfo.CreationTime.ToString();
            label1.Text = creationTime;
        var lastAccessTime = directoryInfo.LastAccessTime;
            label2.Text = lastAccessTime.ToString();
        var lastWriteTime = directoryInfo.LastWriteTime;
            label3.Text = lastWriteTime.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            label1.Text = "";
            label2.Text = "";
            label3.Text = "";
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding DirectoryInfo after iterating through the files.

```
private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name /*+ " (" + DirectorySize(new DirectoryInfo(directoryInfo.FullName)) + " bytes)" + " (" + directoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos().Length + " files)"*/);
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));

    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(new TreeNode(file.Name + " (" + file.Length + " bytes)" + file.CreationTime));

    directoryNode.Tag = directoryInfo;

    return directoryNode;
}
```

Also, you may use FileSystemInfo for Tag, instead of just DirectoryInfo. DirectoryInfo works fine for Directories and Files, however it makes it easy to access the Tag in treeView1_AfterSelected consistently for both Directories and Files if it is FileSystemInfo.

Note that DirectoryInfo and FileInfo are inherited from FileSytemInfo.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't add any tag to the TreeNode created when you loop over the FileInfo array returned by DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()

```
private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{    
    var directoryNode = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name + " (" +  
            DirectorySize(directoryInfo) + 
           " bytes)" + " (" + directoryInfo.GetFileSystemInfos().Length + 
           " files)");
    foreach (var directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(CreateDirectoryNode(directory));

    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        TreeNode node = new TreeNode(file.Name + " (" + file.Length + " bytes)"+ file.CreationTime);
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(node);
        node.Tag = file;
    }

    directoryNode.Tag = directoryInfo;
    return directoryNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`FileInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) to the tree node. Then cast both `DirectoryInfo` and `FileInfo` to `FileSystemInfo` to get creation time, etc.

```
private static TreeNode CreateDirectoryNode(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo)
{    
    //original code...

    // Note: When creating tree node for displaying file,
    // assign FileInfo to fileNode.Tag
    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles()) {
        var fileNode = new TreeNode(file.Name + " (" + file.Length + " bytes)"+ file.CreationTime);
        fileNode.Tag = file;
        directoryNode.Nodes.Add(fileNode);
    }

    //original code...
}


private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    // Note: Both DirectoryInfo and FileInfo, inherrits FileSystemInfo
    // thus you can cast both to FileSystemInfo.
    var fsInfo = treeView1.SelectedNode.Tag as FileSystemInfo;
    if (fsInfo != null)
    {             
        var creationTime = fsInfo.CreationTime.ToString();
            label1.Text = creationTime;
        var lastAccessTime = fsInfo.LastAccessTime;
            label2.Text = lastAccessTime.ToString();
        var lastWriteTime = fsInfo.LastWriteTime;
            label3.Text = lastWriteTime.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        label1.Text = "";
        label2.Text = "";
        label3.Text = "";
    }
}
```